# Inner Join on Same Table Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have written a SQL query and am trying to adapt it to Sequelize but cannot figure out how to create an association on the same table. Here is the SQL:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM `configurations` t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT max(configuration_start) maxConfigStart, pb_id
    FROM `configurations`
    WHERE
        active = 1
        AND DATE(configuration_start) <= DATE(NOW())
    GROUP BY `pb_id`
) t2
  ON t1.`pb_id` = t2.`pb_id`
  AND t1.`configuration_start` = t2.`maxConfigStart`
WHERE t1.`active` = 1
ORDER BY t1.`configuration_start` DESC
```

Here is the model definition:

```
configurations = sequelize.define 'configurations', {
  id:
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER
    primaryKey: true
    autoIncrement: true
  configuration_name: Sequelize.STRING
  configuration_start: Sequelize.DATE
  configuration_end: Sequelize.DATE
  created: Sequelize.DATE
  updated: Sequelize.DATE
}, {
  timestamps: false,
  scopes: {
    currentConfigTimes: {
      attributes: ['pb_id', [sequelize.fn('max', sequelize.col('configuration_start')), 'configuration_start']]
      where:
        active: 1
        configuration_start:
          lte: new Date()
      group: ['pb_id']
    },
    currentConfigIds: {
      attributes: ['pb_id', 'configuration_start', 'id']
      where:
        active: 1
        configuration_start:
          lte: new Date()
      order: [['configuration_start', 'DESC']]
    }
  }
}
```

Any help that someone can offer would be very much appreciated. Essentially I am trying to get the most recent past configuration for every `pb_id`. Maybe there is a better way of doing it?

Comment: You SQL looks no problem and you do not need the last WHERE .... So what is your problem?

Comment: I don't know how to do this in Sequelize. I can do it fine in SQL, but don't know how to transfer it to my ORM.

Comment: The workaroud for now is writing your own raw query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this is actually not possible using Sequelize currently. After spending a great deal of time with their documentation trying to understand the best way of doing this, I came upon [this Github issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/6430) trying to solve the exact same problem. The best solution is to use a raw query at this time.

Comment: any news on this? Did you manage to solve issue without coding raw query?

Comment: As far as I know, no. I haven't used more recent versions of Sequelize though so maybe a solve exists. Feel free to add a comment if you find an answer!

Comment: I've coded a small extension to sequelize that allows you to join with raw queries and custom join conditions. That way I can now do what I needed. If anyone would like access to my fork of sequelize, drop a comment. It's very rudimentary, but will do the job for me.